# App stops when click on notification, open activity from notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

[Screenshot of my logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCi9v.png) I have three tabs  `(extends Fragment)` under `MainActivity(extends AppCompatActivity)`. Third fragment contains a list view, after click on an item it opens another Activity, named `PersonDetailsActivity(through Intent, extends AppCompatActivity)`. I want to show notification checking some condition of list items even when the app is not running. Where should I place and call the notification method. The method works well when I want to open `MainActivity` on click on the notification. My app stops when I try to open `PersonDetailsActivity` on click on notification. **How can I open the list tab (3rd) on touch notification? If I put MainActivity.class in the intent, it opens first tab.** 
Thanks in advance.

Here is my method

```
//Method to show notification
public void showBirthdayNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder)
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications_white_24dp)
                    .setContentTitle("Birthday reminder")
                    .setContentText("It is " +name+ "'s birthday today, " +
                            "wish him/her \"Happy birthday!!\"")
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{250, 250, 250, 250})
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PersonDetailsActivity.class);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent
            .getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    //System.currentTimeMillis();
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
    //notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    mNotifyManager.notify(1, notification);
}
```

Here is my logcat

```
would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
```

11-25 23:02:58.559 23623-23623/com.phoenix.agecalculator I/Choreographer: Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-25 23:03:33.718 23623-23623/com.phoenix.agecalculator D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-25 23:03:33.719 23623-23623/com.phoenix.agecalculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.phoenix.agecalculator, PID: 23623
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.phoenix.agecalculator/com.phoenix.agecalculator.PersonDetailsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                                                                               at com.phoenix.agecalculator.PersonDetailsActivity.onCreate(PersonDetailsActivity.java:183)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

These are the three line in PersonDetailsActivity (line 182, 183, 184 respectively), 183 is highlighted in blue color in logcat

```
byte[] byte_image = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byte_image, 0, byte_image.length); //line 183, I think this is responsible for crash
    civ_profile_image_main.setImageBitmap(image);
```

Comment: share your Crash log with question

Comment: Post your PersonDetailsActivity's code.

Comment: logcat please..

Comment: Unfortunately something happened to my logcat few days before and nothing is there, only blanck screen. How can I post the screenshot here?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<activity
            android:name=".PersonDetailsActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" />
```

in manifest.xml.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer maybe correct, But without logcat..how can you sure?

Comment: because we define MainActivity as launcher activity in manifest that means the start point of the application, so if you're trying to call other activity in application which is not launcher activity through notification this won't work, that's why you have to define PersonalDetailActivity() as launcher in manifest.xml.

Comment: Sorry @NirmalPrajapat, it is not working. Unfortunately something happened to my logcat few days before and nothing is there, only blanck screen

Comment: @Neo ,run you app again and check the logcat in studio

Comment: Nothing happens @NirmalPrajapat, I have posted screen shot of my logcat, did you see that?

Comment: @ Neo , connect your device again , and then run your app again, now select "Show Only Selected Application" instead of No filter. now check the error

Comment: Run your app In debug mode

Comment: Thanks for your time @NirmalPrajapat

Comment: How can I open the list tab (3rd) on touch notification? Can you help me on that @NirmalPrajapat? If I put MainActivity.class in the intent, it opens first tab

Comment: Yes, I am using viewpager for tab layout @NirmalPrajapat

Comment: ohk, just put intent.putExtra("from" , "Notification"); in notification intent where you created notification, now in MainActivity's onCreate() method do Intent intent = getIntent();
String from = intent.getStringExtra("from");
if(from.equalsIgnoreCase("notification"))
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);

Comment: Thank you very much for your support @NirmalPrajapat. You were always there for me. I am glad to say that my problem is solved. PersonDetailsActivity is opening now on notification touch. The crash was happening due to a NullPointerException, I have posted my logcat. I shall try your solution too. android:launchMode="singleTask" this line is not needed. I have one more question for you..In my application if I press back button in PersonDetailsActivity it goes back to list view, but when I open DetailsActivity from notification, on back press it exits from the application. Why is it like so?

Comment: B'coz back button uses a stack which stores all activities, suppose there are 3 activities and the flow is like FirstActivity -> SecondActivity -> ThirdActivity ,here FirstActivity is launcher activity. Now whenever you launch the app FirstActivity will be launched then SecondActivity and then last ThirdActivity. Now if you press back button on ThirdActivity you will be redirected to the SecondActivity, and on pressing back button again you'll be at FirstActivity and by pressing back one more time app will be closed.

Comment: So now in your case you're opening the app through notification which launches ThirdActivity (for example) , and if you press back , back button won't get any activity in stack so it will exit the app.So now you have to manage onBackPressed() in PersonDetailsActivity().

Comment: public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        if(from.equalsIgnoreCase("notification"))
   {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this , ActivityYouWantToCall.class);
        startAcivity(intent);
    }

 }

Comment: Thank you very much for your time @NirmalPrajapat. Sorry for delay, had been busy for some days.

Comment: It's ohk, but are you still getting the problem in code or it is resolved??

Comment: Yes, my problem is solved. It is opening PersonDetailsActivity now. I have posted a new question "Getting trouble to show birthday reminder". Will you please have a look on that? Thanks...